# Make flashbuilder automatically copy compiled swf

Tags: ant, actionscript, flash-builder4.5

I don't know much about ant and I'm having trouble finding an example where I just copy a swf after it is compiled in flashbuilder.  I'm working with a very small swf and I have it set to "build automatically" since the compile time is < .5 sec.

I'd like to shorten the length of my test cycles and I'm hoping to automate moving a file to a folder so I can test the swf in my application.  I only need the file moved when built since that folder auto-uploads anything added to it.  What's the path of least resistance to this automated copy using ant-build.xml?  Is this a simple process or is there a lot of overhead to make this work?  (This is a pure actionscript project imported into a larger application, not flex).  Is this even possible with pure as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple build.xml for Ant, which compiles your MXML application and copies the SWF to a specific folder. Put it into your projects' root folder and replace `bin-release` with your desired export folder. Also adjust the path to your Flex SDK as well as to `flexTasks.jar` and `Application.mxml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Builder" basedir="." default="build">

<target name="init">
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" value="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0" />

    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${basedir}/libs/flexTasks.jar" />
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mxmlc file="${basedir}/src/Application.mxml"
        output="app.swf"
        keep-generated-actionscript="false"
        optimize="true">

        <source-path path-element="${basedir}/src" />
    </mxmlc>
</target>

<target name="export">
    <copy file="app.swf" todir="bin-release" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="init, compile, export" />
```

You can run this build.xml automatically if you add an Ant builder under `Project properties` - `Builders`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a pure AS project, and you're using Flash Builder to build the SWF, all you need to copy the output is a very minimal build.xml, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Builder" basedir="." default="build">

<target name="export-debug">
    <copy file="bin-debug/MyFlash.swf" todir="C:/my/test/path" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="export-debug" />
</project>
```

Change the pathnames as needed and save in the root of your project as build.xml. Now go to **Project -> Properties -> Builders -> New...**, select "**Ant Builder**", and **Browse Workspace** to your build.xml.

Now go to the "**Targets**" tab and configure both the **Manual Build** and **Auto Build** to point to the "export-debug" target.

Now you should have two builders, the built-in compiler, and this Ant target. Whenever the SWF compiles, it will also be copied to the path you specified.